# Parallel ADC IC interface to FIFO Memory

Tags: microcontroller, adc, schematics, memory, fifo

I am referring below schematics attached here.

[image: Schematics]

ADC AD7821KP IC is interfaced with IDT7203 FIFO memory. Now, I want to use 12 Bit ADC in above schematics. But I am not able to find 12 bit FIFO Memory for storing results.

Is there any Memory IC which will be suitable for above application OR any technique to use 9bit as 12 bit memory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a 16-bit wide memory?  Virtually every 10-bit and 12-bit ADC in existence reports 16-bit results, which contains the actual reading plus padding.  You see this both with serial interfaces (SPI, I2C) and embedded peripherals inside microcontrollers.

Comment: Can you suggest us 16 Bit parallel FIFO Memory for 16 bit adc?

Comment: There is 1kx16bit IC from the same architecture/topology, IDT72125. It is only 1k deep instead of 2k as IDT7203 has. But if you can manage syncronous FIFO, there are plenty of bigger chips with 18-bit-wide bus.

Comment: How about something like THS1206 from TI?  It has 4 channels and 6 MSPS sampling rate, so it can replace all 3 of the single-channel 1MSPS ADCs in your image.  And it has a FIFO built-in.  I don't know what the actual requirements for your project are (external trigger?  simultaneous sampling?  multiple references?  programmable gain?) but I suggest you check whether you can find a combination ADC/FIFO chip -- FIFO buffers are a rather common feature on modern ADCs.

Comment: @ Ali Chen ..  If I replace asynchronous fifo with synchronous fifo to have wide 2K x 12 bit memory , can I do that in terms of hardware?

Answer (score 1):

You obviously can't use a 9-bit-wide memory as 12-bits. All you need is to get TWO 9-bit memory chips per channel, one manages the lower 9 bits, and the other IC uses only 3 upper bits, leaving the other 6 unconnected.

The [IDT7203 datasheet](https://www.idt.com/document/dst/7203-7208-datasheet) shows clearly how to expand the bus to N bits wide, see Figure 15.

Comment: @ Ali Chen .. If I replace asynchronous fifo with synchronous fifo to have wide 2K x 12 bit memory , can I do that in terms of hardware?

Comment: @Electroholic, anything is possible in hardware. But you need to carefully examine the output protocol for your ADC, and properly interface it to a different FIFO. If you find no application examples on how to interface this ADC to synchronous FIFO, it means that it might be difficult/inconvenient/too much trouble. Then simply use the suggested expanded solution. Or use a FPGA and design your own FIFO.

Comment: dear Ali, where can I check ADC - Memory compatibility in ADC datasheet ?  Seems that it is not mentioned there..                                                                                   Link for adc datasheet: www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7821.pdf

Comment: @Electroholic, you need to examine control signals for the ADC, and how the output is related to them, understand the waveforms and digital logic behind, what is driving what. Then match this to what is needed for a FIFO.  Again, the AD7821 is 8-bit chip. How do you plan to get 12-bits?

Comment: I will use 12 bit adc (parallel ADC) along with 16 bit fifo synch memory by keeping higher bits unconnected..is it ok?